# Viewing the JSON from an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, django

I have this AJAX call -

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/main/search/",
        data: {
            'search_text': $('#search').val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },

        dataType: 'html'
    });
});
```

The url redirects to a Django view with a template doing something like this -

```
{% if item_list.count > 0 %}
{% for obj in item_list %}
<p>{{obj.name}}</p>
{% endfor %}

{% else %}
No items!
{% endif %}
```

This gives the following alert -

```
<p> Item1 </p>
<p> Item2 </p>
```

and so on, according to the search matches.

Now for learning purposes I want to see how the JSON response would look like, and what I could do with it.
However, this-

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/main/search/",
            data: {
                'search_text': $('#search').val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            },

            dataType: 'json'
        });
    });
```

doesn't even open an alert box.

And, if I look at the "Network" tab in the Chrome inspector, I see that the response is an HTML response just like the previous one.

Why is this happening?
How could I see the JSON response?

Comment: What makes you think there's a JSON response? You only get a JSON response if you actually send JSON from the server, but you're sending HTML. (You're sending JSON *to* the server, but that's not the same thing at all.)

Comment: And where is that determined? Assuming I wanted to receive a JSON object containing information about the matching object, how would that be done?

Comment: By returning JSON from your view.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `console.log(data);`

like this:

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/main/search/",
            data: {
                'search_text': $('#search').val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },

            dataType: 'json'
        });
    });
```

Comment: where on the code are you setting the header as json?

Comment: I got it working by doing what Daniel Roseman suggested - I changed the view to return a json response instead of an html one

Answer (score 0):

You could also open up your console and look in the network tab. From there, you should be able to see all the XHR requests, view the responses, headers, etc

Comment: Already tried that. Response tab shows the HTML, and headers says under 'response headers' - Content-Type:text/html
Even though the data type is set to json. Why is this?

Comment: Are you sure you're returning JSON from the URL you have in your call?